# Jenkins slave unable to install java via yum

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I'm following [this guide](https://d1.awsstatic.com/Projects/P5505030/aws-project_Jenkins-build-server.pdf) and am stuck on configuring my Jenkins slave using my newly created Cloud configuration.

I'm using a public Amazon AMI (ami-062f7200baf2fa504) for the slave.

From clicking on the `Provision via <cloud-name>`, I spin up a new slave and then the logs look as follows:

```
INFO: Connected via SSH.
Feb 12, 2020 8:34:00 AM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: connect fresh as root
Feb 12, 2020 8:34:00 AM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Connecting to 172.31.86.97 on port 22, with timeout 10000.
Feb 12, 2020 8:34:00 AM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Connected via SSH.
Feb 12, 2020 8:34:00 AM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Creating tmp directory (/tmp) if it does not exist
Feb 12, 2020 8:34:00 AM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Verifying: java -fullversion
bash: java: command not found
Feb 12, 2020 8:34:00 AM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Installing: sudo yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Existing lock /var/run/yum.pid: another copy is running as pid 3381.
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
  The other application is: yum
    Memory :  34 M RSS (325 MB VSZ)
    Started: Wed Feb 12 08:33:58 2020 - 00:09 ago
    State  : Sleeping, pid: 3381
...
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
  The other application is: yum
    Memory :  34 M RSS (325 MB VSZ)
    Started: Wed Feb 12 08:33:58 2020 - 00:35 ago
    State  : Sleeping, pid: 3381

 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: amzn2-core/2/x86_64
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://amazonlinux.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2/core/latest/x86_64/mirror.list error was
12: Timeout on http://amazonlinux.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2/core/latest/x86_64/mirror.list: (28, 'Connection timed out after 5000 milliseconds')
Feb 12, 2020 8:35:10 AM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
WARNING: Failed to install: sudo yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64
Feb 12, 2020 8:35:10 AM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Verifying: which scp
/usr/bin/scp
Feb 12, 2020 8:35:10 AM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Copying remoting.jar to: /tmp
```

It seems that my Jenkins slave is unable to install `java` using `yum`? Why is that? I installed java on my master Jenkins instance just fine... Both master and slaves use the same AWS security group with outbound access to anywhere.

Going to `http://amazonlinux.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2/core/latest/x86_64/mirror.list` on Chrome works just fine, the download starts automatically... any clues appreciated on why this error occurred!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a few months old, and you've probably already worked around this issue, but for anyone else... I encountered a similar problem recently that brought me to this page. In my case, jenkins could not install java on the fly because I was using a debian based system that used apt instead of yum as the package manager. It was trying to install java via yum, and that package manager didn't exist on my worker. I think my solution would work for your problem as well, which is to bake java into the ami itself. I used hashicorp's packer, to install java, and other dependencies, into a new ami. Then I configured the jenkins worker to point at my new ami with java pre-installed and the worker was able to connect and run as expected. I think this solution will work for you as well, because then there won't be a race condition in the yum package manager, if java is already installed in the ami that you're using. Here is an article that helped me understand the workflow:
https://medium.com/velotio-perspectives/using-packer-and-terraform-to-setup-jenkins-master-slave-architecture-7bcc4b014874

Comment: appreciate the followup and suggestion! I don't really remember the runaround I did, I think I just swapped to an AMI that had Java...

Comment: Yea. That makes sense and works too. In my case, I wanted to control the contents of the ami to add more dependencies and speed up the jobs that are run on the workers. Previously the workers were using the user data block to install things on top of an empty ami. Pulling latest like this, sometimes causes compatibility issues that would happen randomly. This method also adds time and bandwitdth to every job, which can get expensive. Baking the deps into the ami allows one to isolate regression testing when those dependencies make breaking changes, and cut down on the time jobs take to set up.